# Remove duplicated lines that has few differences

Tags: linux, shell, unix, text, centos

I have a **Dynamic** text file that writes some lines automatically.
But it has a problem with the duplicated entries:

Ex:

```
1111 2222 3333 4444 <- I want this line
5555 6666 7777 8888 <- And this line too
1111 2222 3333 4444
5555 6666 7777 9999 <- Note : 9999 is only one ward change
```

Result expected :

```
1111 2222 3333 4444
5555 6666 7777 8888
```

---

Real Test Ex :

```
exten => 01272786170,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=821)
    same => n,Dial(SIP/port21/01272786170,60,rt)
    same => n,Set(thereis=yes01272786170)
    same => n,Set(calledid=01272786170)
    same => n,GotoIf("calledid" = "01272786170"?ejoin,01272786170,1)
exten => 01272786170,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=826) <- duplicated here with one number change
    same => n,Dial(SIP/port26/01272786170,60,rt) <-
exten => 01272786170,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=827) <-
    same => n,Dial(SIP/port27/01272786170,60,rt) <-
```

Result expected:

```
exten => 01272786170,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=821)
    same => n,Dial(SIP/port21/01272786170,60,rt)
    same => n,Set(thereis=yes01272786170)
    same => n,Set(calledid=01272786170)
    same => n,GotoIf("calledid" = "01272786170"?ejoin,01272786170,1)
```

Note: I want it to be done using Linux Shell.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: I didn't "Give me the codez", I'm explaining the expected results for understanding the question !! with pointing to the problem in the code !!..
Please read the full question first

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and your first sample data:

If you inmplement the Levenshtein algorithm (for example [here](http://awk.freeshell.org/LevenshteinEditDistance)) and come up with adequate edit distance (4 below) you could use this simple approach:

```
awk '
function levdist(str1, str2 ...)  # see the above link for working implementation
{
    ...
}
{
    for(i in a) {                 # iterate all previous stored strings
        l=levdist($0,a[i])        # compute the edit distance
        if(l<=4)                  # if below threshold
            next                  # skip to next string 
    }
    print $0                      # output where threshold was not met
    a[NR]=$0                      # store
}' file
```

Output:

```
1111 2222 3333 4444
5555 6666 7777 8888
```

Comment: I didn't Downvote !!
I still trying to implement it.

Comment: Look at the comments on the question and take a good guess who might have downvoted.